# Issue with Scroll View. Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value

Tags: ios, swift3, scrollview

I have a UIScrollView, and am using a UIPageControl to present images.  The moment the first image appears, the program crashes and indicates a nil value was found.

EDIT:  I'm no longer downloading images for the Scroll View, yet I'm still getting the error.  The image appears and then the program crashes.  Here is the stripped down code.  Totally at a loss at this point.  FYI, the reason I declare the variable i is I intend to loop and add additional images:

```
import UIKit

class HistoryViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        let i = 0
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i)
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size
        let subView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        subView.image = UIImage(named: "maudite")
        subView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.scrollView.addSubview(subView)
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(1), height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
    }
}
```

.....................

I have two theories why this is happening.  The first is that The images for the subView that I add to the ScrollView haven't loaded yet.  I'm using AlamoFireImage, which downloads images asynchronously.
This is the code that configures the Scroll View:

```
func configureScrollView() {
       self.myScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

        for index in 0..<imageURLS.count {
            frame.origin.x = self.myScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
            frame.size = self.myScrollView.frame.size
            let subView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
            if let url = URL(string: imageURLS[index]) {
                subView.af_setImage(withURL: (url))
                subView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                self.myScrollView.addSubview(subView)
            }
        }
        self.myScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.myScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(imageURLS.count), height: self.myScrollView.frame.size.height)

        pageControl.numberOfPages = imageURLS.count
    }
```

The other thing that might be the cause of the issue is that I first have to download the image URL's.  I do this and store them in an array.  When that is complete, I call the configureScrollView().  I do the call on the Main Thread.  Does the function then run on the Main Thread?

```
for dict in responseArray {
                        if let url = dict["fileName"] as? String {
                            let fullURL = "http://www.smarttapp.com" + url
                            print(fullURL)
                        self.imageURLS.append(fullURL)
                    }
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                    self.networkingState = .finishedSearching
                    self.configureScrollView()
                }

        }
```